SSIS complex Excel ideal format
I'm new to SSIS.
I need a complex excel format and generate every month so I use SSIS.
And wondering if it can be used to extract SQL Server data into a new Excel in a specific format?
How can do that??
I still no idea after search on net,
should I Pivot twice?
Ideal Format

Searching for "ssis generate excel" I instantly find step by step tutorials. Please clarify your sepcific problem.
